# How can this bitmap-style text effect be achieved?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, typography, photoshop-effects, bitmap

[image]

I'd like to replicate it but I'm not sure what kind of bitmap would be necessary.

An alternating, vertical line maybe? But then I still don't know how to get the areas of solid.

Comment: indeed, if you know some programming, you can create this effect, I would use bitmap images in this case. Replicating it in vector would be too time consuming and result in too complex structures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how to create something similar in Photoshop...

Create a low res, greyscale document and add your text in a layer as a 50% tint of black (the 50% will give the checkerboard effect later).
[image]
Next add some noise (this will produce the random filled in dots). Go to `Filter > Noise > Add Noise` and pick a low amount to add (I used 15%) then go to `Edit > Fade Add Noise` and change Normal to Darken (because we only want to add dots, not create holes too). The result should look something like this...
[image]
Next, go to Image > Mode > Bitmap and select settings that will keep the same resolution and choose Halftone Screen as the Method, like this...

[image]

Click OK and then choose the following settings (the frequency needs to match the resolution of your image)...

[image]

You will now have a checkerboard pattern with the odd random dots filled in, the last step is to vertically scale this so that the 'dots' are stretched. The final result should look something like this...
[image]

You'll need to tweak the initial resolution and the amount of noise to your tastes and then you just need to colour it up as required.

Comment: Wow... I never know about `Edit → Fade...`. I've been doing that manually for years...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you ask about how to create this effect in the first place and not how to print it.
It can be very easy if you are familiar with programming.
If not, you will need to search, there must be some photoshop plugin/script for that, but I don't know such one. 
Pseudo-code approximately:

```
read your image [h, w] from file
init blocks [k,m] (some different blocks you want to see in the final image)
init image-out [h*k, w*m] (final image, depends on which final resolution you want)
read image pixel 0,0; if true : write  block 1 in image-out 
read image pixel 0,1; if true : write block 2 in image-out 
.. repeat for all values in image
```

This could for example create this diagonal stroke filling.
To add noise effect I would make separate effect and find a way to combine effects, so it is not very simple but not so hard, I think all modern languages have good libraries for such manipulations.

Then save a 1-bit image or format which is you printing software/devices better maintain.
 TIFF format in Adobe world I think is good for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could identify the font and then save the file for web as a bitmap with a pattern, which might give you the similar effect. It will render black and white, but then you could reopen the file to color it.
If you want an exact replica, I would recommend again, identifying the font and then designing the boxes to the same dimensions and filling them in where needed.
Best of luck.